# Including -Inf on ggplot2 axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that look like

```
>head(df_x)
      log10.p. log10.q.
1        -Inf       -Inf
2        -Inf       -Inf
3        -Inf       -Inf
4        -Inf       -Inf
5        -Inf       -Inf
6  -0.7940367 -1.3546946
```

where I plot the log base 10 of two variables that range from (0, 1) on the untransformed scale and (-Inf, 0) when transformed.

The -Inf corresponds to log(0), which is undefined, whereas log(1) = 0

I would like to actually include -Inf in the axis label as in

```
  p <- ggplot(df_pq, aes(x = p, y =  q)) + geom_point(colour = "blue") +
            labs(x = expression(log[10](p)), y = expression(log[10](q))) +
            xlim(-Inf, 0) +
            ylim(-Inf, 0)
```

where the result would plot the infinity symbol at the origin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually the way to do this, is to overwrite "Inf" with some other value, and change the labels such that this value states "inf". You could use [`ggbreak`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html) to make the distance seem "bigger"

Answer (score 2):

Having infinity on a plot is problematic. Without an anti-log transform, the true negative infinity point will always be infinitely far off the bottom of the plot. You can make a *log-like* transform by using a small fractional power transform, and using the log values as labels.

For example, if we have this plot:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, runif(95)))

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)

p
```

[image]

We can do something like this:

```r
dummy_log <- trans_new("dummy", 
                       transform = function(x) x^0.05, 
                       inverse   = function(x) x^20,
                       domain    = c(0, 1))

p + scale_y_continuous(trans = dummy_log, limits = c(0, 1),
                       breaks = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, sqrt(10)/10, 1),
                       labels = ~ifelse(.x == 0, "-\u221e", log10(.x)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit on how you selected the `breaks`; that is, in what way might the chosen values be "optimal" for the given problem at hand?